# How to uncheck select all checkbox when any one of their child got deselected

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, checkboxlist

How can I uncheck the select all `checkbox(parent)`, when any one of their child checkboxes are deselected!

From the snippet when we select all checkbox and when we deselect users from their then select all checkbox should be unchecked (Because all checkboxes are not selected)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Admin').click(function() {
    var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
    $('#tab-10').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
  });

  $('#Sales').click(function() {
    var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
    $('#tab-20').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
  });  
    // i have so may like this in that case how can i do that.?
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-10"> First </a></li>
  <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-20"> Second </a></li>

</ul>

<div class="tab-content vehicle">
  <div id="tab-10" class="tab-pane active">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="Admin"><b>Select All</b></label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="pages[]" value="2">Dealerships</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="pages[]" value="23">Users</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="pages[]" value="59">Third-Party Exports</label>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
<br><br>

<div id="tab-20" class="tab-pane ">
 <div class="panel-body">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="checkbox">
     <label><input type="checkbox" id="Sales"/><b>Select All</b></label>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="checkbox">
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="Second[]" value="2">Second tab 1</label>
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="checkbox">
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="Second[]" value="23">Second tab 1</label>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: Abdul Waheed  did you check the answers?

Comment: what exactly not working? can you tell. Any why to update so late?

Comment: Abdul Waheed  can you check once my code. I have changed it according to your Nw updated HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you din't did any coding regarding your issue (that is when you uncheck any check-box rather than select-all, make select-all unchecked).

Do like below:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Admin').click(function() {
    var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
    $('#tab-10').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
  });
  $('#Sales').click(function() {
    var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
    $('#tab-20').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
  });

  $('.tab-pane').find('input:checkbox:not(:first)').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).closest('.tab-pane').find('input:checkbox:first').prop('checked', false);
    } else {
      var checkbox_length = $(this).closest('.tab-pane').find('input:checkbox:not(:first)').length;
      var checked_check_box_length = $(this).closest('.tab-pane').find('input:checkbox:not(:first):checked').length;
      if (checkbox_length == checked_check_box_length) {
        $(this).closest('.tab-pane').find('input:checkbox:first').prop('checked', true);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-10"> First </a></li>
  <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-20"> Second </a></li>

</ul>

<div class="tab-content vehicle">
  <div id="tab-10" class="tab-pane active">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" id="Admin"><b>Select All</b></label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="pages[]" value="2">Dealerships</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="pages[]" value="23">Users</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="pages[]" value="59">Third-Party Exports</label>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>

  <div id="tab-20" class="tab-pane ">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" id="Sales" /><b>Select All</b></label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="Second[]" value="2">Second tab 1</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="Second[]" value="23">Second tab 1</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working fiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/am6rgdw1/

Comment: It works when i unchecked one of selected checkbox. But when i check all the checkbox individually then Select All are not selected

Comment: it works fine when i checked Select All. But when i check all checkbox individually then Select All Checkbox is not selected. when it will works it will be a perfect solution . :)

Comment: @AbdulWaheed  glad to help you. :):)

Comment: @AlivetoDie can you please check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47055009/check-uncheck-all-checkboxes-with-php

Answer (score 2):

Add the below code to your js:

```
$('input[name="pages[]"]').click(function(){
  $('input[name="pages[]"]').each(function() { 
    var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
    if(!checked){
      $('#Admin').attr('checked', false);
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For Dynamic tab id's i did like this:

This is my html and php:

```
<div class="tab-content vehicle">
<?php  $active='active'; foreach ( $check_menu as $y) {?>
<div id="tabs-<?=$y?>" class="tab-pane <?=$active?>">
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="SelectAll_Dynamic" id="<?=$y?>" />
                <b>Select All</b>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php  foreach($menus as $x): if ($x['parent_id'] ==$y):?>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="pages[]" value="<?=$x['id']?>"
                <?php   if (array_search($x['id'],$my_menu,true))
                    {
                        echo "checked ";
                    }
                ?>
            ><?=$x['name']?></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php  endif; $active="";
    endforeach;?>
</div></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

This is my script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.SelectAll_Dynamic').click(function() {
            var select_Id = this.id;
            var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
            $('#tabs-'+select_Id).find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
            alert(select_Id);
        });

        $('.tab-pane').find('input:checkbox:not(:first)').click(function() {
            if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(this).closest('.tab-pane').find('input:checkbox:first').prop('checked', false);
                } else {
                var checkbox_length = $(this).closest('.tab-pane').find('input:checkbox:not(:first)').length;
                var checked_check_box_length = $(this).closest('.tab-pane').find('input:checkbox:not(:first):checked').length;
                if (checkbox_length == checked_check_box_length) {
                    $(this).closest('.tab-pane').find('input:checkbox:first').prop('checked', true);
                }
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```