# Check/Uncheck (Select All checkbox) if all child check-boxes are selected in that div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

[image]

let me try to explain from image,

1.Reservations, Customers are checked under the tab of Rental vehicles.

2. Now From Rental vehicles tab, both are selected from php code i.e(Reservations, Customers),
3. So now  I want to write a code in **document.ready** to get checked the SelectAll_Dynamic (Select All checkbox),!  because all inner checkboxes (Reservations, Customers) are checked,
4. if anyone from inner checkboxes(either Reservations or Customers) not checked then SelectAll_Dynamic (Select All checkbox)  should be unchecked.

**14 is dynamic.! for every new div its gets changed example: 1,4,6,12 unique..**

```
<div id="tabs-14" class="tab-pane  active">  
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="SelectAll_Dynamic" id="14">
                        <b>Select All</b>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="pages[]" value="41" checked="">Reservations</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="pages[]" value="52" checked="">Customers</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to execute a function after page load, which should check whether all checkboxes are checked or not, apart from the first one which has **SelectAll_Dynamic** class

If all child checkboxes selected then the parent should get selected how can I achieve that..?

This is the functionality which I have for check/uncheck all

```
$('.SelectAll_Dynamic').click(function() {
                var select_Id = this.id;
                var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
                $('#tabs-'+select_Id).find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
            });
            $('.tab-pane').find('input:checkbox:not(:first)').click(function() {
                if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $(this).closest('.tab-pane').find('input:checkbox:first').prop('checked', false);
                    } else {
                    var checkbox_length = $(this).closest('.tab-pane').find('input:checkbox:not(:first)').length;
                    var checked_check_box_length = $(this).closest('.tab-pane').find('input:checkbox:not(:first):checked').length;
                    if (checkbox_length == checked_check_box_length) {
                        $(this).closest('.tab-pane').find('input:checkbox:first').prop('checked', true);
                    }
                }
            });
```

My expected results are:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="SelectAll_Dynamic" id="14" checked> //checked
```

if all child checkboxes are cheked.!

Comment: there's no php here @AbdulWaheed so why is it tagged as such?

Comment: *"I'm talking about page load if all child checkboxes are selected from php code then the parent should be selected"* - There isn't relevant code here. What needs to be done to contain already set values, is to pre-fetch and store those values in a session/cookie. The question is unclear, IMHO. @AbdulWaheed Your inputs have no value.

Comment: ok, this post is starting to look too broad and unclear and wanting code on how to do this. Can you please elaborate on your post by updating it and being honest about it, at the very least? @AbdulWaheed

Comment: @Fred-ii-  I have edited question try to read 4 points once.!

Comment: @AlivetoDie not from php from javascript i want to implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it like below:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tab-pane').each(function(){
    var checkbox_length = $(this).find('input:checkbox:not(:first)').length;
    var checked_check_box_length = $(this).find('input:checkbox:not(:first):checked').length;
    if (checkbox_length == checked_check_box_length) {
      $(this).find('input:checkbox:first').prop('checked', true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs-14" class="tab-pane  active">  
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="SelectAll_Dynamic" id="14">
                        <b>Select All</b>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="pages[]" value="41" checked="">Reservations</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="pages[]" value="52" checked="">Customers</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AbdulWaheed  it will work for each tabs correspondingly without any issue. Glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var allCheckboxes = $('.SelectAll_Dynamic').closest('div[id^="tabs-"]').find('input:checkbox').not(":eq(0)");
var flag = true;
$.each(allCheckboxes, function( i, val ) {
  if($(val).prop('checked') == false)
    flag = false;
});

if(flag)
  $('.SelectAll_Dynamic').prop('checked', true);

$('.SelectAll_Dynamic').click(function() {
                var select_Id = this.id;
                var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
                $('#tabs-'+select_Id).find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
            });
            $('.tab-pane').find('input:checkbox:not(:first)').click(function() {
                if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $(this).closest('.tab-pane').find('input:checkbox:first').prop('checked', false);
                    } else {
                    var checkbox_length = $(this).closest('.tab-pane').find('input:checkbox:not(:first)').length;
                    var checked_check_box_length = $(this).closest('.tab-pane').find('input:checkbox:not(:first):checked').length;
                    if (checkbox_length == checked_check_box_length) {
                        $(this).closest('.tab-pane').find('input:checkbox:first').prop('checked', true);
                    }
                }
            });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs-14" class="tab-pane  active">  
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="SelectAll_Dynamic" id="14">
                        <b>Select All</b>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="pages[]" value="41" checked="">Reservations</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="pages[]" value="52" checked="">Customers</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add the below code in your `$(document).ready` function whick checks if all other checkboxes are checked then check the Select all checkbox.

```
var allCheckboxes = $('.SelectAll_Dynamic').closest('div[id^="tabs-"]').find('input:checkbox').not(":eq(0)");
var flag = true;
$.each(allCheckboxes, function( i, val ) {
  if($(val).prop('checked') == false)
        flag = false;
});

if(flag)
  $('.SelectAll_Dynamic').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: i have added the snippet here

Comment: i haven't used any dynamic value here. m i missing something??

Comment: are there multiple checkboxes with `$('.SelectAll_Dynamic')`?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function SelectAll_Dynamic(){
    if($('.SelectAll_Dynamic').is(':checked')){
        //alert('if');
        $( "input" ).prop( "checked", true );
    } else {
        //alert('else');
        $( "input" ).prop( "checked", false );
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs-14" class="tab-pane  active">  
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="SelectAll_Dynamic" onclick="SelectAll_Dynamic();" id="14" checked>
                        <b>Select All</b>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="pages[]" value="41" checked="">Reservations</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="pages[]" value="52" checked="">Customers</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```